# Scala 2.11: get Class (result of classOf) for type parameters in collections

Tags: scala, types

Say I have an instance of a `Map[K, V]`, `val m = Map[String, Int]("asdf" -> 1)`

and I have a function defined as `def getType[T : TypeTag](t: T) = typeOf[T]`

I can use `getType(m).typeArgs` to get a `List[Type](String, Int)`

How do I get a `List[Class]` for `String` and `Int`? In other words, I want `List(classOf[String], classOf[Int])` as collected from a `Map[String, Int]`, or from any other combination of Map.

My ultimate goal is to write a `RichRow` for a Cassandra `Row`, wherein I can do `(r: Row).getAs[Map[String, Int]]("mymap")`, and under the hood can call `r.getMap("mymap", classOf[String], classOf[Int])`.

Thanks, and good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a `Class` from a `Type` as follows:

```
scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.runtimeClass(tpe)
```

Comment: this looks like it does what I want. Do you know if this works for recursive type args, such as when I might have a List[Option[Int]] for instance?

Comment: If you want to get `classOf[Int]`, you just need to apply this recursively; if you want `classOf[Option[Int]]`, then `Int` doesn't matter, it's the same as `classOf[Option[_]]` and you just apply this directly (except if you have `Array` instead of `Option`).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
def getTypeArgs[T : TypeTag](t: T) = typeOf[T].typeArgs

scala> val m = Map[String, Int]("asdf" -> 1)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(asdf -> 1)

scala> getTypeArgs(m)
res2: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(String, Int)
```